# FIlter data column with value in other file with python

Tags: python

I have the data `file.log`, I want to display all row from the four fields `file.log` that has the same value in the file `list.txt` from the results of other data filters

example value in `list.txt`

```
2
3
7
10
12
etc
```

this is my code

```
import csv

fileopen = open('file.log', 'r')
fileout = open('fileout.txt', 'w')
filefin = open('list.txt', 'r')
for line in fileopen:
        col = line.split(',')
        if len(col) > 1 and col[3] in filefin.readlines():
                fileout.write(line) 
        else:
                pass
fileopen.close()
fileout.close()
```

I have the problem. my code is not running

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
if len(col) > 1 and col[3] in filefin.readlines():
```

`filefin.readlines()` consumes all data from `list.txt`. Once consumed subsequent reads will return an empty string, so all checks after the first will be comparing against the empty string, which will *usually* be `False` (unless `col[3] == ''`) :

```
>>> '123' in ''
False
```

To correct this you can cache the data from `list.txt` in a set object, and use that to perform a quick lookup using the `in` operator:

```
with open('list.txt') as f:
    data_list = set(line.rstrip() for line in f)
```

Each line has trailing whitespace removed with `rstrip()` to remove the new line character.

Then loop over the log file like this:

```
for line in fileopen:
    col = line.split(',')
    if len(col) > 3 and col[3] in data_list:
        fileout.write(line)
```

I changed the column length check to check that the required field is actually present in the data.

---

Your code can be rewritten more succinctly:

```
import csv

with open('list.txt') as f:
    data_list = set(line.rstrip() for line in f)

with open('file.log') as log_file, open('fileout.txt', 'w') as fileout:
    fileout.writelines('{}\n'.format(','.join(row)) for row in csv.reader(log_file) if len(row) > 3 and row[3] in data_list)
```

Comment: I had never considered reading a file into a set object.  Very interesting.  Also, is it true that "set" can act as a list comprehension as you have: set(line.rstrip() for line in f)?

Comment: The `line.rstrip()...` is a generator expression, similar to a list comprehension. I use that to construct a set with the trailing new line characters removed from each line. The set is not behaving like a list comprehension.